# Beginner - Can't install setup.py

Tags: installation, setup.py

I know there's a million topics already on this, but none of them have helped. I'm like a legit beginner, so I have practically no idea what I'm doing. I've got python27 and I've already upgraded pip, along with installing the requests. But when I come to enter 'python setup.py install' it gives the answer no such file or directory. I know I need to change the directory, but pardon my ignorance, how exactly is that done? Everything i've tried seems to result in the same thing..

Comment: Type `python` just by itself. Does it have same error? If so you need to set your PATH so it can find it. What platform are you on? What are you trying to install?

Comment: When I type python just by itself it doesn't provide the same error. I'm on Windows trying to install this: https://github.com/PetterKraabol/Twitch-Chat-Downloader (Twitch-Chat-Downloader by PetterKraabol) Just in case it doesn't let me link, because I've never used this site either lol.

Comment: So you see `setup.py` in the directory that you're in? How about put the actual command you're running and the output

Comment: When I enter 'python setup.py install' it returns 'python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I can find the setup.py if i search the python folder on my C drive manually, but I just can't get the cmd to direct to it, even though I have the path (I think) set to.

Comment: You have to be in the same directory as `setup.py`. Enter `dir` or `dir setup.py` from command line to see if it's there. Change directory using `cd`.

Comment: It says byteyears.py does not exist after I try to change the directory. And when I enter 'dir setup.py' it says file not found.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks MrJLP my main man

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the directory containing `setup.py`, you need to type `python ./setup.py install`.